# Accessing videojs player in react component from other component

Tags: reactjs, video.js

I've used the guide in the videojs docs to create a component that is working correctly (see below).  Once, loaded I can also control the player from the console with API functions like `window.player.play()`.

I would now like to create a play/pause button component.  If I just use `onClick = {window.player.play}`, player doesn't exist when the page loads and causes an error.

I would like the Play/Pause components to be siblings of VideoPlayer:

```
<div>
  <VideoPlayer props />
  <PlayButton />
  <PauseButton />
</div>
```

What is the best way of accessing my player from other components?

```
import React from 'react';

export default class VideoPlayer extends React.Component {
      componentDidMount() {
        // instantiate video.js

    this.player = window.videojs(this.videoNode, this.props, function onPlayerReady() {
      console.log('onPlayerReady', this)
    });
    window.player = this.player;
    }

  // destroy player on unmount
  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.player) {
      this.player.dispose()
    }
  }

  // wrap the player in a div with a `data-vjs-player` attribute
  // so videojs won't create additional wrapper in the DOM
  // see https://github.com/videojs/video.js/pull/3856
  render() {
    return (
      <div data-vjs-player>
        <video ref={ node => this.videoNode = node } className="video-js"></video>
      </div>

    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I assume that your play and pause buttons will be child components of VideoPlayer component. It is correct?

Comment: Ah no - they're going to be top level components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't directly call `window.player` on `onClick` event since it will be called everytime the component renders. `onClick` expects a `function` and hence you can call it like

```
onClick = {() => {if(window.player) {window.player.play()}}}
```

Comment: Check this answer, It should work even when the components are top level components

Comment: Yes it does! - but needed to call play() so -   onClick = {() => {if(window.player) {window.player.play()}}} - is working